# Is there a way to create a shortcut for a system shell virtual directory?

Tags: windows, shell, shortcuts

I wanted to quickly be able to access a system virtual directory, like the "Applications" folder (shell:AppsFolder)

Ive tried just running "shell:AppsFolder" inside a shortcut, but that obviously didnt work.

I know its not that much of a difference but itd be easier not having to run Win+R and typing in the shell link every time I wanted to access a virtual folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to `C:\WINDOWS\EXPLORER.EXE /n,/e,shell:AppsFolder`

I am assuming your `explorer.exe` is in the default location, if not change that part of the link.

Comment: explorer is in Path env variable by default. Hence you can just simple run `EXPLORER /n,/e,shell:AppsFolder`

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder, then drag its address bar icon to your desktop:

[image: Screenshot of File Manager with the address bar icon highlighted]

(In older Windows versions, you could also drag the *titlebar* icon for the same results.)

Answer (score 0):

Create shortcut for this:

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}
```

I got it by Winaero Twеaker app.

Search for an article :

> "CLSID (GUID) shell location list in Windows 10"

from the Winaero Twеaker site.